# can we provide access to blobs/containers/storage accounts using Azure active Directory?

Tags: azure

Can we provide access to blobs or containers or storage accounts using Azure Active Directory?  I have tried to add using AAD but is not permitting to add storage account.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we provide access to blobs or containers or storage accounts using
>   Azure Active Directory?

As of today, it is not possible to provide Azure AD based access to blobs/containers in a storage account. Access to these resources is controlled by storage account keys.

What you can do is restrict the access to management operations on these storage accounts by Azure AD so that only authorized users get access to account keys.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid that you cannot do that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#file-storage-faq

The closest solution you can have is to use shared access keys 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1

Cheers,
Toan Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

Update: this is possible today.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad